# sql in java: WHERE name = variable

Tags: java, sql

This is my code:

```
public static List GetList(String myname) {
    .
    .
    ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM authors WHERE name = ?");
    result.setString(myname);
}
```

I want to select where name = myname (myname is the input of the function).

I tried also something like:

```
WHERE name = @myname
```

but it doesn't work :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't set the value on the *result* but on the *statement*:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM authors WHERE name = ?");
pstmt.setString(1, myname);
ResultSet result = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, a better way to go is to use `PreparedStatement`, to avoid `SQL Injection`: -

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM authors WHERE name = ?");
stmt.setString(1, myname);
ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery();
```

---

However, just to solve your issue, you can use String Concatenation: -

```
stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM authors WHERE name = '" + myname + "'");
```

---

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, you'd be better off with prepared statements here:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM authors WHERE name = ?");
stmt.setString(1, myname);
ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM authors WHERE name = " + myname);
```

Comment: This is not good practice. `PreparedStatement` is the recommended approach.